# Why am I getting incorrect pixel values from PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb, rgba

I am using Pillow to take an average color in a certain range on a photo. It works for all colors except for white, but white was a very red average, which wasn't correct. I decided to isolate the getpixel() method and saw that when I target the coordinates of (1792, 1213) on the below picture, I get the RGB values of (182, 35, 27) from PIL. MS Paint says the color is actually (195, 202, 230).

```
preim = PIL.Image.open("Cube4.jpg")
img = preim.convert('RGB')

print(img.getpixel(1792, 1213))
```

Any ideas on why I am getting conflicting information? It seems that MS Paint is right, not PIL. Below is the image.

[Rubik's Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Np9.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked that ms paint and pillow use the same coordinate systems? i.e., where is (0, 0) in each?

Comment: @Chris looking it up, it looks like PIL uses top left. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html

Comment: Is the linked image really the same you talk about in your question? Pillow, OpenCV, and scikit-image all give `[169, 143, 128]`. So do ImageJ and MS Paint. GIMP asks which color profile to use. The image has some embedded `Display P3` profile (image taken with iPhone?). In general, differences can be caused, for example, by different color profiles used, or different versions of the underlying JPG library like `libjpeg`.